# How to restrict a derive class from accessing one of the property of a base class in c#

Tags: c#

I have a derive(Say B) class in which I want to access some property of a base class(Say A) but not all property of the base class. For ex. I have 5 property say Name, Age, Designation, Location and Salary in a base class which I want to inherit in a derive class. But, I want to acess all the property accept the "Salary" property of the base class(Salary property should not be accessed by the derive class B. How will I achieve it

Thanks in advance.

Comment: By *access*, you mean *write to*?

Comment: what about use `protected`?

Comment: Do you still want other external classes to write to it though?

Comment: Make the property in the base class private.

Comment: @ALZ `protected` would make the property accessible in the derived class. You would want to use private for this...

Comment: Depends of how it's need to access - internal use only (then `protected`), no any access (then `private`)
Read This Found Mention: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wxh6fsc7.aspx

Answer (score 5):

```
public class Employee
{
    public double Salary { get; private set; }
}
```

Assuming:

- you want the property to be readable by everyone
- you don't want subclasses to be able to write to `Salary`

If, however, you want external classes to write to `Salary`, but not subclasses of `Employee`, then that's not possible. Subclasses will always have *at least* as much privileges as external classes.

And if you don't want anyone to be able to read/write to that property (except the `Employee` class), then just make it private like so

```
public class Employee
{
    private double Salary { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I could imagine a _terribly terrible_ "option" where you could have a public setter on the property that analyzes the callstack. If the callstack shows that the write is coming from a derived class it would ignore or throw an exception, and from other external classes it would allow it. (and method inlining would throw it out the window) EDIT: Or perhaps you could analyze caller info attributes if it was rewritten to be a method (not sure if you can use them on properties)

Answer (score 0):

Mark this property as private:

```
class A
{
    protected string Name { get; set; }
    ...
    private string Salary { get; set; } // derived classes has no access now
}
```